# Print lines between two patterns to new file

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed

please help me with this. I have file of following pattern

```
ABC x  
bla bla bla  
bla bla  
bla  
XYZ  
ABC y   
bla bla bla  
bla bla  
bla bla bla  
XYZ  

ABC z  
bla bla bla
XYZ
```

I need output in file x.txt

```
ABC x  
bla bla bla  
bla bla  
bla    
XYZ
```

and

```
ABC y   
bla bla bla  
bla bla  
bla bla bla  
XYZ
```

in y.txt and so on for rest of patterns

Comment: You should try and ask specific questions, please check FAQ

Answer (score 2):

Some like this:

```
awk '/ABC/ {close(f".txt");f=$2} {print >f".txt"}' file
```

This test if line starts with `ABC`and then set output file name to value in `$2`

Eks

```
cat y.txt
ABC y
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
XYZ
```

EDIT: added `close()` to `awk` to close open file so it does not run out of space if it creates many files

Comment: To avoid printing empty lines into these files, you can use `$0{print >f".txt}`, so that if `$0` is empty, the condition won't be matched.

Comment: That may be good and may be bad to do.  If there are space between start end and end pattern, they are lost too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, put all Input into one Array, walk through that with Regex until you find ABC something, open something.txt as Output, continue through your Array printing the lines to Output until you find XYZ and move on.

I assume you know how to write Perl.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $fh;
open my $fh_in, '<', "input_file" or die "unable to open 'input_file: $!";
while (<$fh_in>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^ABC \w+/../XYZ/) {
        if (/^ABC (\w+)/) {
            open $fh, '>', "$1.txt" or die "unable to open '$1.txt': $!";
        }
        print $fh $_,"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sed` as shown below:

```
sed -n '/ABC x/,/XYZ/p' file > x.txt
```

If you know all the patterns, you can use a loop:

```
for i in x y z
do
   sed -n "/ABC $i/,/XYZ/p" file > "$i".txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/ABC/{name="file "$2".txt";}{print >name}' your_file
```