# print lines between patterns individual separate files

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a big file of 5000+ lines which has a repeated pattern like shown below:

```
ABC
111
222
333
XYZ

ABC
444
555
666
777
XYZ

..
..

ABC
777777777
888888888
999999999
222
333
111
XYZ
```

I would like to extract contents between each 'ABC' and 'XYZ' and write it to a separate file.

Ex: file1 should have

```
ABC
111
222
333
XYZ
```

File2 should have

```
ABC
444
555
666
777
XYZ
```

Filen should have

```
ABC
777777777
888888888
999999999
222
333
111
XYZ
```

and so on.

How could we achieve this ? I read these below threads but it writes only one single file. Didn't help for my case.

[How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w/17988834#17988834)

[Print lines between two patterns to new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488355/print-lines-between-two-patterns-to-new-file)

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/^ABC/{file="file"c++}{print >>file}' a
```

Comment: Well done, you could maybe add an ending *session* to avoid empty lines after `XYZ` like `awk '/^ABC/{file="file"c++;w=1}w{print >>file} /^XYZ/{w=0}' a`

Comment: like this; awk '/^ABC/{file="file"c++;a=1}a{print >>file}/^XYZ/{a=0}' a

Comment: right you are fast , i was still to edit /paste reply :-)

Comment: Wow !!! Awk is so powerful...thanks a lot A-Ray ..it worked.  Thanks to NeronLeVelu. Thank you to you both for your help.

Comment: Nicely done, but you probably meant to use `>`, not `>>`, as you'll otherwise _append_ to any _preexisting_ files; sounds like the OP wants to start numbering at _1_, which would make it `++c`.

Comment: Also, it's probably worth closing the previous file before opening a new one so as not to keep opening more and more file handles: `if(file){close(file)} file=...`

Comment: thanks @mklement0, yor are right! use >> more file handles,

Comment: Actually, these are 2 unrelated problems: (a) using `>>` just means that if a given output file already existed before the `awk` command is invoked, it will be _appended_ to; (b) irrespective of whether you use `>` or `>>`, not closing a file explicitly when opening a new one could make you run out of file handles with a large number of output files.

Comment: awk '!a{close(file)}/^ABC/{file="file"c++;a=1}a{print >file}/^XYZ/{a=0}' a

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
< bigfile perl -nwe 'print {$OUT} $_
                         if (/ABC/ && do { open $OUT, ">", "file" . ++$i or die $!}
                            ) ... /XYZ/'
```

- `n` reads the file line by line
- it only prints if between `/ABC/` and `/XYZ/`
- when `/ABC/` is true, i.e. we're starting a new section, a new file is opened and associated with the filehandle `$OUT`. `$i` is the number of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Choroba. I shall keep this perl script and would use it later. Thanks for your time and helping me out.

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest using something other than `${O}` for the file handle, because it is easy to confuse that with `${0}` (zero). With the `-w` flag, you actually do get a warning here about using `$i` only once (Perl v5.18.2); an alternative to omitting `-w` is to prepend `BEGIN{$i}`. Also, given that the opening and closing lines of the range are expected on _different_ lines, it's better to use `...` than `..` - am I correct in assuming that reusing the same file handle implicitly closes the previously open file?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  # setup our output file name file0, file1, file2, ...
  $0 == "ABC"{if (i) {close(f)};f="file"i++;};
  # use inclusive range match 
  $0 == "ABC",$0 == "XYZ"{print > f}
'
```

Comment: Thanks for updating, but from what I understand you don't need to truncate the file explicitly - just use `print > f` in lieu of `print >> f`. The redirection operators inside `awk` work differently from the shell's: in an `awk` script, using `>` in every iteration will NOT recreate the file every time; instead, it will implicitly open/truncate the file on first access, and then keep appending until the file is closed (either explicitly, or implicitly upon termination of `awk`).

Comment: @mklement0 sweet didn't know that. I'm fairly with awk :-)

Comment: @mklement0 sure but can you elaborate a little on what could happen with an unclosed handler? I mean wouldn't it be closed when awk terminates?

Comment: Yes, they would be closed automatically eventually, but with a large number of output files you could run out of file handles before the script finishes.