# Split data separated by spaces

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Suppose I have a dataset with names and registers like

```
John Wayne 1234
Paul Newman 2345 Wrong register. The correct register is 2233
John Fitzgerald Kennedy 3456
Marilyn Monroe 1212
```

All lines are space separated. I want one (or two) regular expressions to use in awk that give me the following outputs:

```
John Wayne
Paul Newman
John Fitzgerald Kennedy
Marilyn Monroe
```

and

```
1234
2233
3456
1212
```

I know the data is in a very, very bad formatting, but does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: you want to have one awk script to generate two outputs? or it is acceptable to have two commands/scripts to generate the two outputs separately?

Comment: It is acceptable to have two scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` could be used for generating the two outputs separately. See the below test:

```
$  cat f
John Wayne 1234
Paul Newman 2345 Wrong register. The correct register is 2233
John Fitzgerald Kennedy 3456
Marilyn Monroe 1212
```

**Output I:**

```
$  grep -o '^[^0-9]\+' f                                          
John Wayne 
Paul Newman 
John Fitzgerald Kennedy 
Marilyn Monroe
```

**Output II:**

```
$  grep -o '[0-9]\+$' f 
1234
2233
3456
1212
```

The regexs used above are relatively straightforward. Using same idea, you could apply the regex with sed or awk too, if you like.

Comment: Nice, but the 1st `grep` command leaves a trailing space on each output line.

Answer (score 1):

This case is fairly simple, since the numbers are after the last separator, so we would treat the last column as if we're unaware of its content like this:

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

For the rest we'll simply match all the letters including spaces until we get to a non-letter character (such as a number) and then we'll just replace all the rest with null:

```
sed 's/\([A-z ]*\) .*/\1/g'
```

Comment: Kudos for a clever, pragmatic `awk` solution, but your `sed` command leaves a trailing space; you could append a 2nd command inside the `sed` script to remedy: `; s/ $//`

Comment: Yes, great (++) - better than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]\+.*$//' file
John Wayne
Paul Newman
John Fitzgerald Kennedy
Marilyn Monroe

sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]\([[:digit:]]\+\)$/\1/' file
1234
2233
3456
1212
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but this lets you do both jobs at once:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

    {
        nums = nums "\n" $NF
        split($0, a, " [0-9]{4}")
        names = names a[1] "\n"
    }

END {
        print names nums
    }
```

First, it takes the last field of the line and adds it to a list of numbers.  Then it splits the line on any 4-digit number and adds the part before the split to a list of names.  Finally, it prints the list of names followed by the list of numbers.

Output:

```
John Wayne
Paul Newman
John Fitzgerald Kennedy
Marilyn Monroe

1234
2233
3456
1212
```

If extraneous spaces are of concern, pipe to `cat -e` to make it very clear where whitespace may have occurred.

Comment: Nicely done, but you should use `" [0-9]{4}"` (note the leading space) to eliminate  a trailing space after the names. Also, `{ print names nums }` (no comma) will avoid a single space on the separator line. Perhaps you can reformat the `awk` command to be multi-line for readability, and provide sample output.

Comment: Good suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating, ++; note that POSIX-like shells such as `bash` do support multi-line string literals, so retaining the _CLI_ form of the solution _combined with a multi-line string_ offers the best of both worlds: readability, while still being able to paste the command into a terminal for quick tests; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33271539/45375) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

awk lets you specify a character set as the field separator. Therefore, if you know that your names are always followed by numbers, you can use:

```
awk -F"[0-9]" '{print $1}' /tmp/x
```

Comment: Nice, but you're only answering half the question (you're extracting the names only, not the numbers). `-F"<space>[0-9]"` (by `<space>` I mean an actual space char.) would eliminate the trailing spaces from the output.